# 18.04: "md" process on non-RAID laptop

Tags: 18.04, icons, mate, mdadm

In the MATE Desktop "System Monitor", I can see a process called [md](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man4/md.4.html). But I'm a little unsure as to whether this actually is the "multiple device" (RAID) driver.

First of all, it has an unusual icon. It's a rectangle with three differently coloured vertical stripes: first blue, then yellow, then red, with some sort of insignia over the top of the yellow. It looks quite like the flag of Andorra as seen at this link:

https://www.quora.com/What-countries-have-blue-yellow-and-red-flags/answer/Milorad-Boti%C4%87-1

(I can't tell for sure as the icon is very small.)

[image]

Secondly, as far as I can tell "md" relates specifically to software RAID. However this is a laptop with only one HD (albeit divided into multiple partitions.)

This process apparently has no open files or memory maps, and running

$ `which md`

in a terminal brings up no results.

Additionally, md does not show in the output of lsmod, and there are no

```
/dev/md*

/dev/md/*

/dev/md/name
```

files on my system, making me wonder if this really is md.

Maybe I'm being paranoid, but this seems a bit fishy to me! Can anyone shed any light, especially on possible ways to get a look at the full-size version of the unusual icon?

**Updates in response to comments - 1**

```
$ grep CONFIG_MD /boot/config-$(uname -r)
CONFIG_MD=y
CONFIG_MD_AUTODETECT=y
CONFIG_MD_LINEAR=m
CONFIG_MD_RAID0=m
CONFIG_MD_RAID1=m
CONFIG_MD_RAID10=m
CONFIG_MD_RAID456=m
CONFIG_MD_MULTIPATH=m
CONFIG_MD_FAULTY=m
CONFIG_MD_CLUSTER=m
#snip all the CONFIG_MDIO results

$ ps -ef | grep -e '\[md\]' -e '\[kthreadd\]'
root         2     0  0 19:06 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root        47     2  0 19:06 ?        00:00:00 [md]
```

Comment: IS RAID, AHCI, or SATA set in your BOS/Firmware?

Comment: Likely the md driver is built in to your kernel by default - take a look at `grep CONFIG_MD_ /boot/config-$(uname -r)` for example

Comment: @steeldriver Here's what I get. Autodetect = yes, the rest of it is as a loadable module - but without an actual RAID array I can't tell why it would have been loaded. Apologies if the line breaks are deleted, that keeps happening when I post comments:

grep CONFIG_MD_ /boot/config-$(uname -r) 

CONFIG_MD_AUTODETECT=y 

CONFIG_MD_LINEAR=m 

CONFIG_MD_RAID0=m 

CONFIG_MD_RAID1=m 

CONFIG_MD_RAID10=m 

CONFIG_MD_RAID456=m 

CONFIG_MD_MULTIPATH=m 

CONFIG_MD_FAULTY=m 

CONFIG_MD_CLUSTER=m

Comment: Apologies, I shouldn't have second guessed myself and added the trailing `_` - probably the relevant kernel config entry is simply `CONFIG_MD`, which is likely set to `y`. Can you also edit your question to include the output of `ps -ef | grep -e '\[md\]' -e '\[kthreadd\]'` please

Comment: Just checked and CONFIG_MD is indeed set to y

Comment: @steeldriver Question edited to include the output of that command line (I have rebooted my box today, so PIDs might have changed.) Also to show the status of CONFIG_MD and the CONFIG_MD_ entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the low PID, what you are likely seeing is a kernel thread. For example, on my system (which also does not have any RAID devices, nor either of the raid packages `mdadm` `dmraid` installed) I see the following:

```
$ ps -ef | grep -e '\[md\]' -e '\[kthreadd\]'
root         2     0  0 Mar10 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root        35     2  0 Mar10 ?        00:00:00 [md]
```

(note the `md` process's PPID is the PID of `kthreadd`).

Looking at my kernel config file, I see that `MD` is configured as a built-in (so you won't see it using `lsmod`):

```
$ grep CONFIG_MD= /boot/config-`uname -r`
CONFIG_MD=y
```

although most other RAID capability *is* provided by modules. According to [Managing RAID on Linux](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/managing-raid-on/9780596802035/ch04s01.html), `CONFIG_MD` is also required for LVM - so perhaps that is why it is enabled by default.

---

To figure out why your system monitor is showing a different icon for this kernel thread in particular takes some sleuthing. Looking at the source code for `gnome-system-monitor` (on which I believe the Mate system monitor is based) we see in `./src/prettytable.cpp` the following function:

```
void
PrettyTable::set_icon(ProcInfo &info)
{
  typedef Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf>
    (PrettyTable::*Getter)(const ProcInfo &);

  static std::vector<Getter> getters;

  if (getters.empty())
    {
      getters.push_back(&PrettyTable::get_icon_from_gio);
#ifdef HAVE_WNCK
      getters.push_back(&PrettyTable::get_icon_from_wnck);
#endif
      getters.push_back(&PrettyTable::get_icon_from_theme);
      getters.push_back(&PrettyTable::get_icon_from_default);
      getters.push_back(&PrettyTable::get_icon_from_name);
      if (has_kthreadd())
        {
          procman_debug("kthreadd is running with PID 2");
          getters.push_back(&PrettyTable::get_icon_for_kernel);
        }
      getters.push_back(&PrettyTable::get_icon_dummy);
    }

  Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf> icon;

  for (size_t i = 0; not icon and i < getters.size(); ++i) {
    try {
      icon = (this->*getters[i])(info);
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
      g_warning("Failed to load icon for %s(%u) : %s", info.name.c_str(), info.pid, e.what());
      continue;
    }
    catch (Glib::Exception& e) {
      g_warning("Failed to load icon for %s(%u) : %s", info.name.c_str(), info.pid, e.what().c_str());
      continue;
    }
  }

  info.set_icon(icon);
}
```

The gist seems to be that it constructs a list of icon "getters", and then tries each in turn until it finds a match, eventually falling through to `get_icon_for_kernel` in the case of kernel thread processes - this is the one that returns the default `applications-system` "cogwheel" icon that you see for the other processes:

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf>
PrettyTable::get_icon_for_kernel(const ProcInfo &info)
{
  if (is_kthread(info))
    return Glib::wrap(gtk_icon_theme_load_icon (gtk_icon_theme_get_default (), "applications-system", APP_ICON_SIZE, GTK_ICON_LOOKUP_USE_BUILTIN, NULL));

  return Glib::RefPtr<Gdk::Pixbuf>();
}
```

So it seems likely that one of the higher priority "getters" is erroneously returning an unrelated icon for the `md` process. If we guess that might be based on the process name, then we are looking for some software package that installs an icon named `md`. One candidate from standard Ubuntu repositories is

```
mate-icon-theme: /usr/share/icons/mate/scalable/animations/md.svg
```

[image]

which is the flag of the [Republic of Moldova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moldova), whose [ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code is md](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#MD).

Comment: Regarding the cog icon - one of the reasons I'm concerned is that all of the other kernel threads in System Monitor have the cog icon. It's only this one that doesn't.

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern I suspect that what's happening is that (1) system monitor has an algorithm for assigning icons that first searches by name and possibly other attributes before falling through to the generic `applications-system` (cog) icon; (2) you have some software on your system that provides an icon named `md` (possibly `/usr/share/phpldapadmin/htdocs/images/countries/md.png` from `phpldapadmin`) and (3) it is the flag of the [Republic of Moldova](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moldova), whose ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 code is [md](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#MD)

Comment: Bingo! On my system, it's /usr/share/icons/mate/scalable/animations/md.svg (So many cool-looking flags in that folder.) If you edit the information from that comment into your answer, I'll mark it as the accepted answer. Many thanks indeed for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

The first step, as always, is read `man md`. or https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man4/md.4.html

Would booting with the kernel paramater `raid=noautodetect` (as described in `man md`) help you?